# How to load a div and refresh mysql query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, load

I have searched the archives and have tried the examples given, but still no luck. What I am trying to do is reload a div and query the "uid" variable. Do I need to use secondary file for this action or can it be done on the same page? Any positive help is much appreciated.

the HTML:

```
<a id="cms-user-list1" href="#" onclick="clickToSlide(this.id, 'cms-user-orders-detail', '65');return false;">
```

the Javascript:

```
function clickToSlide(er, cr, user_id)
{
    var pathtopage = 'blah.php';
    var a = parseInt($('#'+cr).css("left"));

    if (a ==50) {
        //SLIDE DIV LEFT AND LOAD UID
        $('#'+cr).animate({"left": "+=600px"}, "slow").load(pathtopage, {uid: user_id});

    } else {
        //SLIDE CURRENT DIV RIGHT, LOAD NEW UID AND SLIDE LEFT
        $('#'+cr).animate({"left": "-=600px"}, "slow"); 
        $('#'+cr).animate({"left": "+=600px"}, "slow").load(pathtopage, {uid: user_id});
    }       
}
```

**UPDATE 3/7**

I wasn't able to find the exact solution to my problem so I went with posting the data to a 2nd PHP file it works great! Now I'm having problems with the animation. Can I get another pair of eyes on this to see where I went wrong?

```
function populateDetails(er, div, url, user_id) {        

    var a = parseInt($('#'+div).css("left"), 10);

    // ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type  : 'POST',
         url  : url,
         data : "uid="+user_id,
         beforeSend : function() {
             $('#'+div).html('processing');
         },
         error : function() {
             alert("Something went wrong. Try again.");
         },
         // success callback
         success : function (response) {
            if (a ==50) {
                $('#'+div).animate({"left": "+=600px"}, "slow").html(response);
            } else {
                $('#'+div).animate({"left": "-=600px"}, "slow").html('', function() {
                   $('#'+div).html(response).animate({"left": "+=600px"}, "slow"); // im not certain if `this` will work here
                });
            }            
         },
         timeout : 3000,
    });
};
```

Comment: Don't forget tu use radix parameter for `parseInt` : `parseInt($('#'+cr).css("left"), 10);`

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't really like to use jQuery so I my code might not work!

I don't see why you can't re-use the same file (although you might need to do something to make sure it doesn't cache it locally)

I think you might want to change how you handle loading/reloading the div.

The following (hopefully) will slide the container away, and start the (re)load of the content, then once the load is complete slide the container back. (hope the chaining order is correct, not sure what direction they execute!)

```
$('#'+cr).animate({"left": "-=600px"}, "slow").load(pathtopage, {"uid": user_id}, function() {
   $(this).animate({"left": "+=600px"}, "slow"); // im not certain if `this` will work here
});
```

You could possibly have the `.load()` fired by the `animate()` complete callback to avoid possible flashing of content.

**Update**

I think your problem is that your arguments `er`, `div`, `url` and `user_id` are getting lost (I don't know this for a fact). I've added the context parameter, and changed your `$('#'+div)` to `$(this)` and re-ordered your last `.html()` thing as it does not have a callback, its the `.animate()` that does.

```
function populateDetails(er, div, url, user_id) {        
     $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: 'uid='+user_id;
        context: $('#'+div),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(this).html('processing');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Something went wrong!");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            var a = parseInt($(this).css('left'), 10); 
            if (a == 50) {
                $(this).animate({'left': '+=600px'}, 'slow').html(response);
            } else {
                $(this).animate({'left': '-=600px'}, 'slow', function() {
                    $(this).html(response).animate({"left": "+=600px"}, "slow");
                }).html('');
            }   
        },
        timeout: 3000
     });
};
```

If you could describe the "problem" a bit more it would be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks. The .animate code already works fine, but I'll try your out for the sake of being efficient. My problem is reloading the div with the new user_id

Comment: I wasn't able to find the exact solution to my problem so I went with posting the data to 2nd PHP file it works great! Now I'm having problems with the animation. Can someone check to see where I went wrong? `var a = parseInt($('#'+div).css("left"), 10);   if (a ==50) {
    $('#'+div).animate({"left": "+=600px"}, "slow").html(response);
   } else {
    $('#'+div).animate({"left": "-=600px"}, "slow").html('', function() {
       $('#'+div).html(response).animate({"left": "+=600px"}, "slow");
    });
   }`

Comment: Adding this to the bottom of your question would make it a lot easier to read :) and let people who might be new to the question get the whole story

Comment: Sorry, new to posting questions here. I didn't see that I can edit.